# UTF-8 Encoding ; Only some Japanese characters are not getting converted

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf

I am getting the parameter value as parameter from the **Jersey Web Service**, which is in Japaneses characters.

Here, **'japaneseString'** is the web service parameter containing the characters in japanese language.

```
   String name = new String(japaneseString.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

However, I am able to convert a few sting literals successfully, while some of them are creating problems.

The following were successfully converted:

```
 1) アップル
 2) 赤
 3) 世丕且且世两上与丑万丣丕且丗丕
 4) 世世丗丈
```

While these din't:

```
 1) ひほわれよう
 2) 存在する
```

When I further investigated, i found that these 2 strings are getting converted in to some JUNK characters.

```
 1) Input: ひほわれよう        Output : �?��?��?れよ�?�
 2) Input: 存在する            Output: 存在�?�る
```

Any idea why some of the japanese characters are not converted properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Why encoding and decoding a string in the same line? That does not make sense. Obviously, `japaneseString` is already a string, so you can simply use that in the code instead of `name`. As an answer: `String.getBytes()` uses the platform's default encoding for creating the byte array. And this might not be UTF-8. The decoding process with UTF-8 then will produce the junk chars.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Its a silly question but I have to ask it anyway: you're sure the font used can actually render all those characters, right?

Comment: @Gimby: Yes, the others are rendering absolutely right.

Comment: The 3rd and 4th strings does not look like Japanese. I am not sure if UTF for Kanji and Hiragana are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with JVM parameter file.encoding to set with value UTF-8 in startup of Tomcat(JVM).
E.x.:  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Answer (score 13):

You are mixing concepts here.

A `String` is just a sequence of characters (`char`s); **a `String` in itself has no encoding at all**. For what it's worth, replace `characters` in the above with `carrier pigeons`. Same thing. A carrier pigeon has no encoding. Neither does a `char`. (1)

What you are doing here:

```
new String(x.getBytes(), "UTF-8")
```

is a "poor man's encoding/decoding process". You will probably have noticed that there are two versions of `.getBytes()`: one where you pass a charset as an argument and the other where you don't.

If you don't, and that is what happens here, it means you will get the result of the *encoding process* using your *default* character set; and then you try and re-decode this byte sequence using UTF-8.

Don't do that. Just take in the string as it comes. If, however, you have trouble reading the original byte stream into a string, it means you use a `Reader` with the wrong charset. Fix *that* part.

For more information, read [this link](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html).

(1) the fact that, in fact, a `char` is a UTF-16 code unit is irrelevant to this discussion

Comment: Please see the JAVA Doc it is not re-encoding the bytes again in UTF-8. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[], java.nio.charset.Charset)  Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the specified charset.

Comment: @Nitul yes it does. See the documentation for `.getBytes()` and the constructor which is called here.

Comment: Can you give the solution, how to decode the string into UTF-8, without calling getBytes method().

Comment: @Nitul read the answer again; a String has no notion of decoding or encoding at all; you only encode char sequences to byte sequences, and decode byte sequences into char sequences. The initial problem, if any, is that the OP fails to _decode_ the byte sequence properly.

Comment: @Nitul UTF-8 is an encoding! You do not _decode a string into UTF-8_. A string is a simple char array, and chars do not have any inherent encoding. A character is simply a value pointing into a character table. An encoding is used for storing that character (the character's value) as one or more bytes. Nothing else. And the decoding process is the opposite: Take some bytes and create characters according to the used encoding.

Comment: Even if the `String` class most probably will be implemented using a sequence or array of `char`s, the definition of a `String` instance is even more abstract: 'The String class represents character strings.' The String class can just as well use an UTF-8 encoded byte array or an int array with code points as internal storage and still fulfill the API contract.

Answer (score 4):

I concur with @fge.

***Clarification***

In java `String/char/Reader/Writer` handle (Unicode) text, and can combine all scripts in the world.

And `byte[]/InputStream/OutputStream` are binary data, which need an indication of some encoding to be converted to String.

In your case `japaneseStingr` should already be a correct String, or be substituted by the original `byte[]`.

***Traps in Java***

Encoding often is an optional parameter, which then defaults to the platform encoding. You fell in that trap too:

```
String s = "...";
byte[] b = s.getBytes(); // Platform encoding, non-portable.
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8"); // Explicit
byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // Explicit,
                         //  better (for UTF-8, ISO-8859-1)
```

*In general avoid the overloaded methods without encoding parameter, as they are for current-computer only data: non-portable. For completeness: classes FileReader/FileWriter should be avoided as they even provide no encoding parameters.*

***Error***

`japaneseString` is already wrong. So you have to read that right.
It could have been read erroneouslyas Windows-1252 (Windows Latin-1) and suffered when recoding to UTF-8. Evidently only some cases get messed up.

Maybe you had:

```
String japanesString = new String(bytes);
```

instead of:

```
String japanesString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

At the end:

```
String name = japaneseString;
```

Show the code for reading japaneseString for further help.