# Apache CXF/JAXB unmarshaller converting Japanese characters to ? marks java

Tags: java, xml, cxf

Apache CXF/JAXB is not unmarshaling Japanese characters. If we are printing the xml using System.out.println output is coming properly like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employee id="1470">
    <designation>Eng</designation>
    <name>マデュ</name>
    <salary>20000.0</salary>
</employee>
```

If we are passing the same XML to CXF layer it is converting like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employee id="1470">
    <designation>Eng</designation>
    <name>???</name>
    <salary>20000.0</salary>
</employee>
```

How to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you saw the output xml with '???'? Can you share the code for the conversion?

Comment: JAXBContext pContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(target);
      sw = new StringWriter();
      Marshaller marshaller = pContext.createMarshaller();
      marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
      marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
      marshaller.marshal(pObject, sw);

Answer (score 0):

Can you try use PrintWriter on top of StringWriter?

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
```

Can you try with XMLEventWriter to System.out?

```
        XMLEventFactory events = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        QName bar = new QName("urn:bar", "bar");
        XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory.IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES, true);
        XMLEventWriter writer = factory.createXMLEventWriter(System.out);


        JAXBContext pContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(target); 


        Marshaller marshaller = pContext.createMarshaller(); 
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); 
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE); 
        marshaller.marshal(pObject, writer); 

        writer.add(events.createStartDocument());
        writer.setDefaultNamespace("urn:bar");
        writer.add(events.createStartElement(bar, null, null));
        writer.add(events.createEndDocument());
        writer.flush();
```

Comment: Getting javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException after adding PrintWriter.

Comment: Can try above for XMLEventWriter to System.out?

Comment: Still getting same exception. Here my concern is how to marshal/unmarshal japan characters.

Comment: And also setting the encoding as utf-8 also no use. can you please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009119/utf-8-encoding-only-some-japanese-characters-are-not-getting-converted