# Convert Japanese string to double byte format in java

Tags: java, type-conversion

I want to convert Japanese String to double byte format. Not sure how to do it. Have been stuck here since past 2 days.

I tried out some coding below but it didn't work . Japanese string is in sMessage

System.out.println(sMessage);

```
        String jMessage = new String(sMessage.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(jMessage);


                sMessage.getBytes();

        System.out.println(sMessage);
```

Comment: *"but it didn't work"* This isn't a proper problem description. Please read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you define "double byte format"?

Comment: Without knowing how the string is encoded, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: By "double byte", do you mean UTF-16? You have to know if you want `UTF-16LE` or `UTF-16BE`

Comment: Have you already looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009119/utf-8-encoding-only-some-japanese-characters-are-not-getting-converted ?

Comment: And you want what exactly? This more and more sounds like an XY problem, so why don't you start by saying what you want to achieve? Also, a hint: **a `String` has no encoding**.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I believe you want to do

```
sMessage.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

You need to define what charset should be used when converting to a byte array. Otherwise it will use the default, read from the environment variable

```
file.encoding
```

Note that UTF-8 does not mean "double byte format", it can be up to 4 bytes per character.

https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8