# Character showing up as diamond question mark only at end of line (Python>Text)

Tags: python, text, character, utf

I'm working on a Python file that inputs a text file with Japanese characters (UTF-8) in it, takes some of the text, and writes it into a new UTF-8 text file.

The problem I'm coming across is that for some reason whenever the Japanese character だ appears at the end of a line in the original input file, it comes out as a diamond question mark in the output file.

Instances of だ before the end of a line read perfectly fine and the original input file has it reading perfectly fine even if it's at the end of the line.

Comment: using python 2.7 or 3.x? python 3.x has much better unicode support

Comment: here the explanation is for Java but it's relevant here as well
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24009294/1530987

Comment: Please share code snippet.

Answer (score 5):

As you haven't shared any code snippet I would recommend you a generic way of reading and writing `utf-8` files using the `codecs` module as:

```
# Reading utf-8 encoded file
with codecs.open("in.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as input_data:
    data = input_data.read()

# Write utf-8 encoded file
with codecs.open("out.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_data:
     output_data.write(data)
```

And BTW I tested it on the given character だ and it works pretty fine.