# double quotes showing as diamond shaped question mark in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am on Windows 8 and writing a Python (Python 3.6.5) program to get some data from a webpage.  I am getting the result and displaying it on the screen using print() function.

When it prints it out, it shows me diamond shaped question mark instead of double quotes, I know that it is an encoding conflict.

Please advise how to resolve this problem.

Comment: You can get the answer from here . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812162/character-showing-up-as-diamond-question-mark-only-at-end-of-line-pythontext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Character showing up as diamond question mark only at end of line (Python>Text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812162/character-showing-up-as-diamond-question-mark-only-at-end-of-line-pythontext)